# Classcastexception When Using Custom TextView Class

Tags: android, textview, classcastexception

I've been using a custom class ("AutoResizeTextView") that extends `TextView` (see the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)).  However, when trying to initialize this AutoResizeTextView, I get a `classcastexception.`

Here is some code:

**Splash.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    ...
    // Line that causes error ------v
    final AutoResizeTextView appName = (AutoResizeTextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);

    ...
}
```

**splash.xml:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="35dp" />
```

**Logcat:**

```
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.projects.package.name.Splash}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at my.projects.package.name.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:44)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-01 10:43:33.471: E/AndroidRuntime(6433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

---

I assumed that since this custom class extends `TextView`, and since `R.id.title_text` is a `TextView`, this would work.  Any ideas what's going wrong?

Some things I've tried:

- Project -> Clean
- Restart Eclipse
- Ensure every file exists where the code is attempting to find it at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your problem:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="35dp" />
```

istead of  `<TextView` you should indicate your custom `TextView` in this way:

```
<your.package.AutoResizeTextView 
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="35dp" />
```

Comment: You should use <TextView class="your.package.AutoResizeTextView "

Comment: @botond, class can be used with <View. Both are valid solutions

Answer (score 1):

You are `TextView` to your custom `AutoResizeTextView`
just change little bit in your xml

```
<yourpackagename.AutoResizeTextView
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="35dp" />
```